# Entity Type : Categories is missing from dropdown (Export - Data Flow Profile) Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, category, export

i just want to export all categories , the issue is when i use export DataFlow Profiles, i Just See  in Entity type Customers & Products, there is no Categories option in Dropdown, anyone please help me.
See the below image

[image]